# Binge.com.au video streams not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: streaming

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have subscribed to the new Binge.com.au video streaming service offered by Foxtel.

When trying to stream via Ubuntu, it freezes at 20% buffer. I have tried multiple browsers- brave, chrome, firefox and have the same issue.

I have tested it out on a Windows computer and this streaming service works fine.

Does anyone know what can cause this issue in Ubuntu? Or has come across a similar issue?

Comment: What browser are you using? could not find "ares-can-use-high-drm on the inspect. Please detail how to find it.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to let you know I have found a temporary work around to play a movie on binge.com.au, inspect the element by right clicking the video/error and inspect, then chose the Application tab in DevTools, select Local Storage for Binge and where it says "ares-playback-details" edit the array of into and change 'canPlayHighDrm' from "false" to "true".

Refresh the page and press play and it should work! :)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how did you find it, but that was amazing and worked well for me. Thank you very much for that info.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer from @Aaron_L, I have created an extension for firefox. It can be downloaded here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/binge-on-linux/

This should hopefully be a more permanent fix to the issue.

Source code: https://github.com/masterneko/binge-on-linux

**Note**: Firefox does not play nicely with binge and glitches alot, so I recommend using chromium. I did not publish the extension to the chrome web store but you can download the crx file [here](https://github.com/caelwithcats/binge-on-linux/raw/master/chrome.crx). You can load the extension by turning on developer mode, refreshing and then drag the file into the extensions page in chrome

Comment: you are a champ!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem. Turned out they use HEVC codec for streaming which is not supported natively by any browser [(except for Safari)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=hevc). In windows all browsers delegate it to the system itself (thus you can watch Binge even in MS Edge or latest IE), but as far as I can see, at the moment there is no "linux" way to watch it.

You either need to use a virtual machine with Win or organise dualboot or use your mobile phone.

Comment: Wow that's no good, have you tried running Safari via wine? Does that work?